# hide app_id to the user and adjust content accordingly

Tags: php

I have an application on which I would like to display two different contents based on a certain `app_id` when the user is connected. I don't want the `app_id` to be shown to the user (so he won't be able to modify it). Therefore I don't wanna send it as a queryString. The application main file is `index.php`. So, when the user access `index.php` I want to adjust the content according to the `app_id`. Any idea how I can pass that `app_id` to `index.php`, without showing it to the user?

I was thinking about `$_SESSION` but because there is only one `index.php` file, I can't really do something like this:

```
if($_SESSION['app_id'] == 1)
{
    // call index.php file of app 1
}
else
{
    // call index.php file of app 2
}
```

I don't want to duplicate the content. I want to keep everything in the same file and use conditions to display the correct elements based on the `app_id`.

Thanks for any help

Comment: Well somehow you have to transfer the app id, there is no way around that. And that can be seen, regardless of how you do it. All you can do is try to obfuscate it, so send it in a non obvious manner. Probably the best hidden way is to not send it in an explicit manner at all, but to implement different behavior of the app. Then on the server side you can recognize that behavior and act accordingly. An easier alternative would be to send an additional http header with the version number.

Answer (score 0):

Because http is stateless and passing the app_id in query string is not a option for you I suggest the next concept.

Store the app_id in a session or a cookie; If you mind that a user may not modify the app_id I suggest session over cookie. Because a value of cookie can be modified by the user so then you end up with the same issue.

Store the app_id into a session and load the app_id value into factory method pattern;

Check for further explanations of the design pattern "fatcory method" over here; http://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/factory_method.

Basically the design pattern is responsible to create the desire "app_id" instance. By that you can organise your code much better plus if you have a new "app_id" just define a new app class and define it into the factory method class.
By that it also doesn't infect your entire codebase because your encapsulate the creation of your app instance and you can easily using the instance in your entire code base (of course if that is needed)

I hope this helps for you